# Show Custom Members as Axis-X in Power BI

Tags: charts, powerbi, ssas, mdx

I'm using `SSAS` and `Power BI` with Live connection. please consider this scenario:

I should calculate yearly growth (It is measured every year compared to the previous year) so I wrote this `Calculated Member (Measure)`:

```
IIF(( [Measures].[Amount], [Dim Dates].[Calendar Year].PREVMEMBER) = 0 OR
    ([Measures].[Amount] , [Dim Dates].[Calendar Year].CURRENTMEMBER) = null OR
    ([Measures].[Amount] , [Dim Dates].[Calendar Year].PREVMEMBER) = null,
null,
(
  ([Measures].[Amount] , [Dim Dates].[Calendar Year].CURRENTMEMBER) 
  -
  ([Measures].[Amount] , [Dim Dates].[Calendar Year].PREVMEMBER))
  /
  ([Measures].[Amount] , [Dim Dates].[Calendar Year].PREVMEMBER)
)
```

So it generates:

```
Calendar Year              YearlyGrowth
----------------------------------------
2016                         1.7
2017                         -2.3
2018                         8.7
...
```

but I want to show a chart like this:

[image]

and I want to show **[Previous Year - Current Year]**. How can I do this with `SSAS` and `Power BI`.

Comment: Can you not define a calculated column in SSAS?

Comment: Yea I can define it

Comment: Then you define a calculated column similar to what melvin suggests for a measure and use that as your axis.

Answer (score 0):

You already seem to have completed the hard part. To get the specified format you can create another measure:

```
CalcYear = "[" & FORMAT('Table'[Calendar year],"#") & "-" & FORMAT(('Table'[Calendar year]+1),"#") &"]"
```

This calculation should give you the output in the desire format. You can use this in creating your chart. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure that he can create DAX measures with Live Connection to SSAS Cube.

Comment: Is the measure in the question created in the cube? If so, you should be able to apply the same concept as the answer in the cube

Comment: I can'y using `DAX` in live connection. But I'll check your solution

Comment: If you can't use DAX then the only way would be the cube. You should be able to do something similar in the cube

Answer (score 0):

The link below explains how to generate analysis report which may solve your above asked question.....:

Generating charts in SQL Server Reporting Services through [how to create chart](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/generating-charts-in-sql-server-reporting-services)

Custom sort order for axis, columns in Power BI [custom chart in Power BI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BnB4xUNisSA)